# MySqlDbType tiny(4) doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I'm adding parameters to a MySqlCommand and I have a column declared as Tiny(4) but that type doesn't exist in MySqlDbType.
Also the data in my code is a string "0" or "1".

```
 If ActiveModifChk.Checked Then
        ActiveStr = "1"
 Else
        ActiveStr = "0"
 End If

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@isActive", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = ActiveStr
```

What MySqlDbType should I use?

Comment: TinyInt equivalent of Byte or SByte in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`MySqlDbType` enumeration reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDbType.htm), use either `MySqlDbType.Byte` or `MySqlDbType.UByte` depending on either signed or unsigned definition to handle `tinyint` data type:

```
// signed 8-bit
cmd.Parameters.Add("@isActive", MySqlDbType.Byte).Value = sbyte.Parse(ActiveStr);

// unsigned 8-bit
cmd.Parameters.Add("@isActive", MySqlDbType.UByte).Value = byte.Parse(ActiveStr);
```

If you just passing 'zero' or 'one' (which resembles `true` or `false` condition), use `MySqlDbType.Bit` and define `bit` data type to corresponding parameter/column.